# Should I use null or an empty Container when I don't want to render a widget according to the app platform?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to use a FloatingActionButton only if the platform is Android:

```
floatingActionButton: Platform.isIOS
  ? null
  : FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: ...
    ),
```

Should I render an empty container instead? How should I deal with widgets that I don't want under specific conditions overall? Is it bad convention to use null widgets?

Comment: try replace null to const SizeBox.shrink()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not** bad convention to use null widgets.

Check from Flutter's source code, you could see the following:

```
class Scaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Creates a visual scaffold for material design widgets.
  const Scaffold({
    Key? key,
    this.appBar,
    this.body,
    this.floatingActionButton,
    ...
   }

    final Widget? floatingActionButton;

}
```

`floatingActionButton`  is optional as designed.

If you not use the property `floatingActionButton` , `floatingActionButton`  is null too.

---

So **not** need render an empty container instead.To deal with widgets that *I* don't want under specific conditions overall, it is **ok** to use null widgets